# Will app store approved application when they don't get their 30% cut?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have created a course site, let’s say 10 courses. Each price is $1.00. Now I have each course have ios application. If user pays for my course from desktop site, they can use same course from application also.

Now see, if user has downloaded my free app. If user wants to purchase, I have put up a link which redirects user to my desktop site and purchase course. Once he purchased course, he will be back to ipad app and learn course.

In short apple will not get its 30%. Will these going to be approved by app store when they don't get their 30% cut

Comment: Very doubtful.  You will need to use In-App Purchasing.

Comment: Is the course downloaded and distributed through the app? Oh actually, just read it again. Yeah, I don't think Apple will allow it.

Comment: The applications I make do the same thing, the user fills the data out within the app then the user is sent to a website to make the payment, however there is a small difference between mine and yours is the amount £/$ taken. My applications take thousands of £/$ so we have an agreement with Apple that basically says yeah it would be stupid to take 30%. Also Apples in-app purchase didn't even go the amount we wanted.

Comment: Popeye - did they approved it?

Comment: Yes they did but this was in agreement with apple to have this and it took about a year to actually get this approval. Also the price that a customer would pay is never the same and changes based on a risk so the higher the risk the more you pay, think of it like insurance.

Answer (score 2):

The rule is pretty easy, the hard part is how Apple review team will understand the contents that you provide in your app.

If your contents can enhance or complete the app somehow and is distributed in a digital format Apple will require the integration of In App Purchase.
I remember that I've read from a blog a case similar to yours. The writer was complaining that the review team was constantly rejecting its app, because it was selling a CDROM containing an HTML course (I guess) that was "started" in the app. The end of the story is that he was able to put the app to Appstore but after a lot of rejecting. Once the Apple review team had understood that he was selling physical good they released the app.
I your case I think that IAP is the way to go. 
Reading the point [11 of App store review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#purchasing-currencies) will answer some questions.